# Trying to recreate Rally's Release Cumulative Flow chart with the new API

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have it done with with version 1.19 but 2.0 makes no sense to me. I want to get multiple graphs for different releases on the same page which is why I can't use the built in one.

Comment: What is your question?